# push another view from detail View

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I have a big problem: on method didSelectRowAtIndexPath I always get null to self.navigationController.I have a project based on SplitViewController, and I want to push another view when a row are selected in a details TableView.

Architecture:

```
LoginView->SplitViewController->Master
                               ->Detail->AnotherView
```

My AppDelegate.m : load the login form

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   

    // Initialize the app window
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    AuthentificationViewController *authentificationViewController =[[AuthentificationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthentificationView" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController=authentificationViewController;

    [authentificationViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:authentificationViewController animated:YES];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Inside interface of AppDelagate I have those property :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
```

Method handle When we Click on Cancel button on a login form

```
- (IBAction)btnCancel:(id)sender {

   AppDelegate* app_delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //self.window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    app_delegate.window.rootViewController= app_delegate.splitViewController;

}
```

When we select a row we have this Method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      if([indexPath row] == 0)
            {

                // show add bookmark controller

                BookmarkEditorController* bookmarkEditorController = [[[BookmarkEditorController alloc] initWithBookmark:[[ComputerBookmark alloc] initWithBaseDefaultParameters]] autorelease];

                [bookmarkEditorController setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ajouter Connexion", @"Add Connection title")];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookmarkEditorController animated:YES];

}
```

But Nothing is happen when I select a row and navigationController is nil please how can I fix it???

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      UIViewController *localdetailViewController =nil;
       if([indexPath row] == 0)
        {

            // show add bookmark controller

            BookmarkEditorController* bookmarkEditorController = [[[BookmarkEditorController alloc] initWithBookmark:[[ComputerBookmark alloc] initWithBaseDefaultParameters]] autorelease];

            [bookmarkEditorController setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ajouter Connexion", @"Add Connection title")];

            localdetailViewController=bookmarkEditorController;
             AppDelegate *delegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            NSArray *viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0],bookmarkEditorController,nil];
            delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers=viewControllers;



        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this [Link](http://remapps.net/2011/01/25/split-view-controller-switching-detail-view-controllers/)
,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
UIViewController* myVCToReplace = nil;
  if(indexPath.row == 1)
       myVCToReplace = [myVC1 alloc]init];
  else
       myVCToReplace = [myVC2 alloc]init]; 

  NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:MySplitVC.viewControllers];
      [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:myReplacementVC];
      MySplitVC.viewControllers = arr;
      [arr release];
```

Comment: Bonnie I follow the Link but I have same error "self.navigationController" is null

Comment: dude dont have to push the view in Master's Navigation as ur doin now, you have to set the splitviewContollers detailView to a navigation controller and push now view onto the detailNavigation not self.navigation

Comment: this is the important part 
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 
[navController pushViewController:localdetailViewController animated:YES];
 
TutorialSplitViewAppDelegate *delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 
NSArray *viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0],navController,nil];
 
delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

Comment: Bonnie I edit the Topic please look my method and tell me If I am on the right way

Comment: try this istead of adding a navigation controller just add the detailView to the Splitview ViewController' array
 NSArray *viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0],bookmarkEditorController,nil];
delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers=viewControllers;

Comment: Bonnie I edit the the method in the topic but When I click on the row nothing is happen

Comment: please check your delegate.splitViewController is not nil.

Comment: delegate.splitViewController is nil

Comment: is the splitview synthesized. in the appDelegate if not please synthesize the splitView

Comment: Yes splitview is synthesized

Comment: u say your project is a masterDetail based broject , right,?? but in your appDelegate there is no code to set the Master and Detail for the splitView, where have you done this.?

Comment: Because I have an Login View Before the splitView I set it insite the Login VieW Controller When I click on "Cancel Button"  - (IBAction)btnCancel:(id)sender {

   AppDelegate* app_delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //self.window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    app_delegate.window.rootViewController= app_delegate.splitViewController;

}

Comment: Bonnie are you still there??